# S3AsyncClient resume multipart upload after application restart

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, multipart-upload

I'm using `S3AsyncClient` client in Java to upload a big file using multipart upload.

If the application restarts during upload, a new `S3AsyncClient` instance is created with a new `uploadId`.

Is it possible to complete a multipart upload with a new `uploadId`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to complete a multipart upload with a new `uploadId`?

No, you require the same `uploadId` used to first initiate the multipart upload.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

I have uploaded total of 20 parts (1GB). Half of them have initial uploaId, rest have uploadId retreived after process restart. Partnumbers are 1-20.

When completing multipart upload, I get exception S3Exception: One or more of the specified parts could not be found. The part may not have been uploaded, or the specified entity tag may not match the part's entity tag. 

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: `uploadId retreived after process restart` - is this a new uploadId? If new, you will need to reinitiate the upload with either the old ID or the new ID. Either way, it may then pick up and upload the missing parts.

Comment: Yes, that is the new uploadId.
I don't know how to "reinitate the upload with either the old ID or new ID". Could you explain this?

Comment: Please create a new question :)